# HTML Conversion with external css

Tags: java, itext

I have tried to convert HTML to PDF using java iText API and it is working fine as well but the problem is API is not allowing to include the external CSS.

Can any one tell me how to convert html with external css to pdf?

Comment: Can you not inline the css? (It was a long time ago that I used itext, so this is probably a silly question.)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i can not inline the css because css can be modified in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can inline CSS in your code, using for example [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net) library.

You have on their page the ready code sample:
http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/ConvertStyleSheets.java